# RDP session fails for "Unknown extended disconnection reason 4399"

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-access

I am trying to log into a jumphost using Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7. Normally I have no issue. Today I got this error code:

```
Disconnected from xxx.xxx.xxx-xxx.edu
[Unknown extended disconnection reason 4399]
```

a search revealed [this Microsoft article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37870.rds-remote-desktop-client-disconnect-codes-and-reasons.aspx#Extended_Disconnect_Reasons) which lists reason codes for this very scenario, unfortunatley, (at the time of this writing) the list jumps from reason code 4339 to reason code 4498.

I suspect that my session got hung up somehow as I disconnected last time, as opposed to logging out.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: My repeated attempts are jumping between unknown extended disconnection reason 15 and 4399. Unfortunately reason 15 is also undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today.  I had a very old disconnected session still on the host.  I logged the session out remotely with RDC Manager, and I was then able to start a new RDP session.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check if the port is open?, also the health of the server you are connecting to, is the service running?